# Matlab - How to output a for loop as a table with each iteration and result displayed

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am wondering how to output a for loop in Matlab so that I end up with a table where the first column is the iteration number and the second column is the result of each iteration. I want the results of each iteration to display not just the final answer.

As a very simple example I have the for loop function below.

Thanks.

```
p=10
for i=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
    p=2*p
end
```

Comment: do you mean [this `table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `i` is the iteration variable, so you can reference it to get the iteration number.

I'm assuming you meant you want to output an array (not an actual [table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) data structure). To make an array, you can use some simple concatenation:

```
p = 10;
arr = [];
for i = 1:9 % shortcutting your manual method here
   arr = [arr; i p]; % concatenate the current array with the new row
   p = p .* 2;
end
```

Which results in:

```
arr =

       1          10
       2          20
       3          40
       4          80
       5         160
       6         320
       7         640
       8        1280
       9        2560
```

If you actually want a table, then you can create the table from the array using the `table` function